# Use Georeferencer GDAL plugin on QGIS to create a GeoTIFF if the latitude and longitude boundaries are known for a raster image

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, latitude-longitude

What I have/know:

- I know the latitude and longitude boundaries for an image
- I am using the EPSG:4326 projection
- QGIS with the Georeferencer GDAL Plugin Installed

Is it possible to create the georeferenced image without going through the steps of finding matching points between the image and lat/lng points on the EPSG:4326 projection?

Is there some way to just enter the W S E N boundaries and have the image georeferenced?

Comment: Because geographic coordinates are angular measurements, the quality of the transform could be problematic with just corner points. A lot depends on the rotation and obliqueness of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could build your own control point file with a text editor.  Then import that text file inside the QGIS georeferencer.
Here is an example of a control point file on windows named myfile.points.  You would need to add your own PROJCSR stuff.  Keep in mind that the image origin is 0, 0 in the upper left corner of the image with positive values for Y below the datum and positive values for x right of the datum.
[image]

And then [this website](https://kokoalberti.com/articles/georeferencing-and-digitizing-old-maps-with-gdal/) provides instructions on a pure GDAL approach to the same problem.